# bourbon, neat, and bitters conflict

Tags: css, sass, bourbon, neat

I have installed:
sass-3.4.22
 bourbon 5.0.0-beta.6
bitters-1.4.0
neat-1.8.0
They are set up in the CSS directory of my project under the base, bourbon, and neat directories like normal.

In my .scss sheet I have:

```
    @import "bourbon/bourbon";
    @import "base/base";
    @import "neat/neat";
    $font-stack: Raleway, sans-serif;
    $base-color: #4286f4; 
    #main{
          @include outer-container();
          @include linear-gradient(to top, $base-color, lighten($base-color, 20%));
          font-family: $font-stack;
    }
```

Sass throws the error Undefined mixin 'linear-gradient'. If I get rid of bitters and neat then linear-gradient works (but `@include outer-container();)` doesn't of course.

What am I missing? I thought that using bourbon would speed things up and be more light-weight than bootstrap, but so far it is just slowing me up!

Thanks

Comment: You have probably checked this, but latest bitters looks like it is using `core` rather than `base` as it's main directory. Is it definitely `base` in your case?

Comment: Thanks- I'll check that. Also, It might also be a case of them taking out some "features", like auto-prefixing, without really updating the docs.

Comment: Yeah - it's always a gamble using a Beta, you never know quite what you will get!

Answer (score 1):

The `linear-gradient` mixin has been removed in Bourbon 5. The best source right now for finding these removals is the [Change Log](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), specifically [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed-2). The Bourbon website docs represent v4, which is the current stable release, and not v5.

Comment: Thoughtbot is (correctly) suggesting not using prefixing mixins, such as `linear-gradient()` in favor of using some sort of [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer). Hence, the removal.